# Ubuntu install (replacing Elementary OS) fails after BIOS

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, acer

I have an Acer Aspire M5-583P laptop which has ElementaryOS on it as its main OS. I was going to replace it with Ubuntu but while installing (from USB drive) an error occurred; it stopped installing and logged me off. So I had to shutdown by holding the power button.

When I try to reboot from the USB drive, after it gives me a selection from where to reboot from, it doesn't do anything-- just stays at a black screen, instead of taking me to Yumi to choose which distro to launch.

So I restarted the laptop again this time choosing to go into BIOS but after I enter my password it goes to a black screen as well. Can't do anything there..

So I restarted again and I just let it boot on its own and it just gets stuck on the Acer logo menu where it says press f2 for bios or f12 for boot options.. I have no idea what to do, I am scared that my laptop has become corrupt and unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest, on another machine, completely erase the USB flash drive before putting just Ubuntu back on to create an Ubuntu-onlu LiveUSB, then use that to reboot and do an {F12} reinstall. I've made that transition myself (although I used Xubuntu not Ubuntu) and it worked flawlessly on my Thinkpads, both models SL400 and R60.

Comment: I tried doing something similar to that (different distro tho) but the problem of going into Yumi still remains. So I am stuck at a black screen that hangs there forever.

Comment: Yes I reformatted it. Only Bodhi is currently on it... Would resetting the BIOS help?? Because I can't seem to do anything..

Comment: Please completely erase the USB flash drive before putting just Ubuntu back on it, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Resetting the Bios would be your only option at this point. Cause as you stated that it just sits and hangs on the acer screen at boot. Sounds to me you have some kinda corrupt POST going on in the BIOS. Try that and start from scratch.